# SQLite unrecognized token exception in Insert

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I get `unrecognized token error` when I try to include the `Api_key` column and its value in my insert query, otherwise without it, it works fine.

here's the code:

```
public void InsertResult(String apikey,String auditid,String crit_id, int current_chap)
{
    String s="INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Results(AuditID,CriteriaID,ChapterID,Api_key) VALUES("+auditid+","+crit_id+","+current_chap+","+apikey+")";

    sp.execSQL(s);
}
```

Here's my logcat:

```
10-11 22:45:09.655: E/AndroidRuntime(8124): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oxtro.trustea/com.oxtro.trustea.ChapterActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token: "3249f6dc" (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Results(AuditID,CriteriaID,ChapterID,Api_key) VALUES(1,13,13,3249f6dc-c3ca-4c8d-a4de-df1834c579c4)
```

Answer (score 15):

You should put tick marks around your non-numeric strings.

```
String s="INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Results(AuditID,CriteriaID,ChapterID,Api_key) VALUES("+auditid+","+crit_id+","+current_chap+",`"+apikey+"`)";
```

Note the ` marks around "apikey"

SQLite was seeing the `-` and getting confused why it wasn't in a string.

Comment: You should mark the answer as correct so the question goes into a resolved state.

Comment: @LS_dev I totally agree, I was just answering his question.

Comment: Quick note: problem was nor `-`, was alphanumeric digits. If it were `2345-2344` it would perform arithmetic and use result. Problem was parsing `3249f6dc`: not a number neither function, ...

Answer (score 8):

Don't ever hardcode strings in your SQL statements.

User inputted strings create a SQL injection vulnerability.

Arbitrary strings needs to be parsed fro special characters.

SQL APIs normally provide bind methods to allow you to safelly insert arbitrary data in you database.

In Android SQLite, for `INSERT` you may use:

```
public void InsertResult(String apikey,String auditid,String crit_id, int current_chap)
{
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
    cv.put("AuditID", auditid);
    cv.put("CriteriaID", crit_id);
    cv.put("ChapterID", current_chap);
    cv.put("Api_key", apikey);
    sp.insert("Results", null, cv);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Apikey is a String so for sql you need to place it inside quotes.
`String s="INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Results(AuditID,CriteriaID,ChapterID,Api_key) VALUES("+auditid+","+crit_id+","+current_chap+",'"+apikey+"')";`